React router: create two routes that renders same component with different state
I'm using createBrowserRouter to render a component that changes its inner state depending on the route. Which is the best approach to let this component to know in which route its in?
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "layout/backup/make",
    Component: Backup
  },
  {
    path: "layout/backup/restore",
    Component: Backup
  }
]);


Use the useMatch hook inside the component to determine what the URL is.

Use the element property instead of Component! Then you can pass props to your Backup component.
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "layout/backup/make",
    element: <Backup foo />
  },
  {
    path: "layout/backup/restore",
    element: <Backup bar />
  }
]);

